# Ng2 Nativescript Webpack - ERROR in Could not resolve module @ angular/core

Tags: angular, webpack, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, angular2-aot

I have angular2 Nativescript project where I have implemented lazy loading. I am now trying to implement webpack with AOT as per the directions given by nativescript - here.
Accordingly, I installed the plugin : nativescript-dev-webpack and .

Now when I run, npm run start-android-bundle, I get the following error:

```
`ERROR in Could not resolve module @angular/core

ERROR in ./main.aot.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.module.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\krithika\MyProjects\questNewS\app'
@ ./main.aot.ts 3:0-60
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin C:\Users\krithika\MyProjects\questNewS\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist C:\Users\krithika\MyProjects\questNewS\node_modules\resolve-url-loader\index.js??ref--1-1!C:\Users\krithika\MyProjects\questNewS\node_modules\nativescript-css-loader\index.js??ref--1-2!C:\Users\krithika\MyProjects\questNewS\node_modules\nativescript-dev-webpack\platform-css-loader.js!C:\Users\krithika\MyProjects\questNewS\app\app.css:
[1] ../node_modules/resolve-url-loader?{"silent":true,"absolute":false,"sourceMap":false,"fail":false,"keepQuery":false,"debug":false,"root":null,"includeRoot":false}!../node_modules/nativescript-css-loader?{"minimize":false}!../node_modules/nativescript-dev-webpack/platform-css-loader.js!./app.css 925 bytes {0} [built]
+ 2 hidden modules
Webpack Bundle Analyzer saved stats file to C:\Users\krithika\MyProjects\questNewS\report\stats.json
Webpack Bundle Analyzer saved report to C:\Users\krithika\MyProjects\questNewS\report\report.html
child process exited with code 2

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\krithika\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "ns-bundle" "--android" "--build-app"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ ns-bundle: ns-bundle
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ ns-bundle script 'ns-bundle'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! ns-bundle
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR! npm bugs
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! C:\Users\krithika\MyProjects\questNewS\npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\krithika\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "build-android-bundle"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ build-android-bundle: npm run ns-bundle --android --build-app
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ build-android-bundle script 'npm run ns-bundle --android --build-app'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! npm run ns-bundle --android --build-app
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR! npm bugs
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! C:\Users\krithika\MyProjects\questNewS\npm-debug.log`
```

Also, in my code I find that the ts file gives me an error saying "cannot find module @angular/core". Similar errors are occurring for "ui/page" and "rxjs/Rx"

I have done the following things to fix this problem with no success -

- removed node_modules, hooks and platforms and added them again
- changed "enhanced-resolve" to 3.3.0 as mentioned [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-webpack/issues/233)
- changed the templates and style references to relative paths
  Please suggest what I could to try so that I can get webpack to work in my project.

Comment: Have you tried running the correct android webpack build command `npm run ns-bundle --android --build-app`?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon thanks, tried what you suggested. It resulted in the same error log.